# Regular expression for street address with special characters

Tags: c#, regex

Can anyone please provide a regular expression which will match the following string.

```
"190 Rock's Cage-cafe"
```

My current pattern is

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9]+[_\-' ]+$";
```

But that does not work.

Comment: add some more explanation to your post because a simple `.*` will do this job. Based on your regex, you could try this  `^[A-Za-z0-9]+[_\-' A-Za-z0-9]+$` also.

Comment: You should read the FAQ regarding how to ask questions.

Comment: or `@"^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9'_-]+)+$"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below regex would match all the lines which has atleast two words where the first word won't contain any character other than letter or digit. And the following one or more words are composed of letters or digits or underscore or hyphen or single quotes.

```
@"^[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:\s[A-Za-z0-9'_-]+)+$"
```